# Printing structure varibales at a particular point

Tags: c++, c, unix, gdb

Lets say we have a structure with some variables.

Is it possible to values of those variables at a particular point of execution..?

One way might be to print each of them individually.

But my point is, is there a way to check values of all the variables in that structure at a particular point of time, without having to use printf or cout to print each variable value..?

Just wondering if this is possible atleast in gdb..!!

Comment: GDB prints all structure members when you print an instance of the structure. Did you try it? Note that you have to dereference pointers-to-structures first. Printing a pointer only prints its address.

Answer (score 2):

it is possible in gdb, no problem:

For example:

x.C

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  int x;
  int y;
};

int main(int argc,char **argv) {
   A a;
   a.x=10;
   a.y=11;
   std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
}
```

compiling:

> g++ -g -o x x.C

running on gdb

> gdb x

```
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40096c: file x.C, line 10.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/jsantand/x 

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffde98) at x.C:10
10     a.x=10;
(gdb) next
11     a.y=11;
(gdb) next
12     std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
(gdb) print a
$1 = {x = 10, y = 11}
(gdb) quit
```

Doing that on your code, traces, etc... it will be be more difficult as C++ lacks reflection.

You could do it by hand or if you're adventurous, create something to generate automatically operator<< for your classes an structs/classes so that they provide a string representation. You need some basic C++ parser at least.